# Apache ProxyPassReverse with parameters from request

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I've a situation where I want to redirect everything that starts with /app to an internal server. Basically the idea is that Apache will work as a reverse proxy doing the following conversion:

```
http://external/app -> http://myserver:1082/myapp
```

I was able to do it using Rewrite, as follows:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app
  RewriteRule ^/app(.*)$ http://myserver:1082/myapp$1 [L,P]

  ProxyPassReverse /app http://myserver:1082/myapp
```

It works fine. The issue is that now I'm gonna have a language preffix on the URL, but no on the application. So I need the following redirection:

```
http://external/app -> http://myserver:1082/myapp
http://external/en/app -> http://myserver:1082/myapp
http://external/pt/app -> http://myserver:1082/myapp
```

While this can be done with the rewrite, I have a problem with the proxyPassReverse. Because basically I need to do a dynamic ProxyPassRever that, depending on the actual URL request by the user, changes the Location

```
ProxyPassReverse /en/app http://myserver:1082/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /pt/app http://myserver:1082/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /app http://myserver:1082/myapp
```

It would be something like

```
ProxyPassReverse ${preffix}/app http://myserver:1082/myapp
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

From [ProxyPathReverse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse):

> When used inside a  section, the first argument is omitted and the local directory is obtained from the .

From [Location](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#location):

> The URL may use wildcards. In a wild-card string, ? matches any single character, and * matches any sequences of characters.
>   Extended regular expressions can also be used, with the addition of the ~ character.

So you should be able to use:

```
<Location /[a-z]+/app>
    ProxyPathReverse http://myserver:1082/myapp
</Location>
```

Comment: Actually, that does not work, since it replaces "http://myserver:1082/myapp" for the literal string "/[a-z]+", instead of using the actual path that matched the regular expression

Comment: Where does it do this replacement?

Comment: On the affected headers on the response.